# How do I find error logs for my Python lambda function across many AWS Cloudwatch log streams?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Let's say I have log group `/aws/lambda/backend`, which tracks logs of my Python lambda function.
I want to debug common issues, like exceptions and time outs, and find related log entries.

But the function has a lot of concurrent traffic, so there are many log streams in the log group.
How do I find the log entries across all logs without visiting each individual log stream and perform the search?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible by using [Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html), which uses a query language to analyze logs in a log group.

For common Python function errors, I find [this query](https://gist.github.com/oleksii-donoha/b28bae9e9a1dbec8d9f45eb214029395) useful:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| filter @message like /(?i)Exception|Error|Traceback|Timed out/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

This will return log queries and links to log groups to places, where exceptions or timeouts happened.